# how do I get the full R console output?

Tags: r, console

I've made a regression analysis which gives me a lot of lines in the console. I need to see the output to select the optimal model. But I can only scroll through some of the output in the console.

How can I change this so that I can se all of the output from my code?

Thank you,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ' I can only scroll through some of the output in the console' - could you post a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. Are you using RStudio? Rgui? Emacs/ESS? Jupyter? RNotebook? RStudio server? Something else?

Comment: I'm using Rstudio and running a chunk of code, where the output is then send to the concole. Its about selecting variables in a regression analysis. There's a lot of variables that the code needs to run through in the type of analysis and thus many lines to be printed in the console. However I can only see some of these. I need to see them all to select the optimal model :-).

Comment: @MariaHoffmannJensen I think that my answer already solved this for you - did you try it out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple reproducible example to demonstrate:

```
f = function(n) for (i in 1:n) print (paste('Line', i)) 
f(5000)
```

Running this in RStudio, I can only scroll back to see the final 1000 or so lines

Using `capture.output` we can save the output to either a character vector or an external file.

```
out = capture.output(f(5000)) # save in character vector

fname = tempfile()
capture.output(f(5000), file = fname) # save in file
```

An alternative method to send the output to a file is to use `sink`

```
sink(fname)
f(5000)
sink()
```